# Asset Compress Plugin for CakePHP not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, yui, minify, cakephp-2.2

I'm having troubles to compress my Javascript files using [Asset Compress Plugin for CakePHP 2.X](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress). I'm currently using CakePHP 2.2.2 over IIS 7.

It tries to add the compressed `js` file but it doesn't exist:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakephp/cache_js/jquery-combined.v1379067166.js">
```

- I have downloaded and placed the plugin under `app/Plugin/AssetCompress/`
- I have dowloaded [YUI build tool](http://yuilibrary.com/download/builder/) and placed the file contained in `lib/yuicompressor/yuicompressor-2.4.2` in `vendors/yuicompressor/`
- I have made the folder `webroot/cache_js/` writable.

This is my `asset_compress.ini`:

```
[General]
cacheConfig = false

[js]
timestamp = true
path = WEBROOT/js/*
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_js/
filters[] = YuiJs

[jquery-combined.js]
files[] = jquery.tipsy.js
files[] = web.js
```

And I am adding the plugin in bootstrap like this with `debug` mode set to `0`:

```
Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
    'AssetDispatcher',
    'CacheDispatcher'
));

CakePlugin::load('AssetCompress', array('bootstrap' => true));
```

Also, I'm loading it from the `AppController`:

```
var $helpers = array('AssetCompress.AssetCompress');
```

And using it on the `layout` template in this way:

```
echo $this->AssetCompress->script('jquery-combined');
```

The only error I'm getting on the `error.log` is the following one:

> 2013-09-13 14:16:10 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller
>   class CacheJsController could not be found.
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php(92): Dispatcher-> dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\index.php(42): require('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
>   {main}

Any clue about what can be happening? 
Should I have Java SDK installed ? Am I picking the wrong `.jar` file from YUI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can set debug = 0 you need to use the CLI tool to build static versions of the assets. I'm pretty sure this is in the documentation.

Comment: What is the purpose of having to build them "manually" using the console at first? Won't the plugin suppose to build them automatically? I'm not sure to understand the purpose of those assets (AssetDispatcher, CacheDispatcher) and it seems not to be explained in the documentation.

Comment: Is it only to avoid creating them if there are no changes the first time? Cache purpose for the first time?

Comment: Also, if your build has any errors, this may happen too.